# Add an Approved By Column and Approved by Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, flow

I have created a Flow arround document approvals.

It is triggered when the document status is set to pending, and begins working through a normal flow (sent to approver etc etc.)

However what i want to do is add an additional column that stipulates who the approver was, and the date approved. I have added this to the flow to change the document properties. Unfortunately this edits the document so it gets set to Draft again!

Is there anyway to update these properties without triggering the version control again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the SharePoint i.e. when you update any field value it gets set to Draft again and if versioning is enabled in document library then it will increase version as well.

Here only solution is to set approval status once again to Pending and then Approved.

[image]

**Reference Link**

https://tomriha.com/how-to-set-content-approval-status-with-power-automate/